# Regarding Better Approach of Handling Properties

Tags: java

I need to read the two of the following attributes of user details through properties file.

```
username and userid.
```

There may be `n` number of users inside the properties file.The number is not fixed.
In this case what is the best practice to handle this requirement using properties file in java.

How about using the following approach.

Inside the properties file :

```
 userA = Jhon#001
   userB = Smith#002
   userC = Snack#003
```

Please provide your pointers on the same.

Comment: Do you use `userA`, `userB` and `userC` somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer a XML for this approach

```
<users>
   <user>
       <username>John</username>
       <userid>001</userid>
    </user>
    <user>
       <username>Smith</username>
       <userid>002</userid>
   </user>
</users>
```

Comment: I prefer property files. It's much smaller and don't require xml parsing. If there is some other properties then XML is better but for simple key-value storage I'd prefer properties.

Comment: if that is the case seems your approach is ok, but I will do like user.1=John#001

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JSON format, smaller then XML and much faster

```
{"users": [
  { "userid":"01" , "username":"Jhon" }, 
  { "userid":"02" , "username":"Smith" }
  { "userid":"03" , "username":"SmithX" },    
  ]
}
```

Comment: Need to provide a way for the operator to add new user on demand basis.Is this JSON is user friendly in that perspective?

Comment: Yes JSON is very readable and also there are many free editors both online/offline available

Answer (score 0):

As @guess_me [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14395813/1479414) , XML approach would be better.

But if you strongly need use `.properties` file, then it would be better to add numbers of persons to the key values:

```
 user#001 = Jhon
 user#002 = Smith
 user#003 = Snack
```

Comment: I don't see why there is need for `user#` part. If property file contains only users then it's reduntant.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I can not understand you idea. If we are talking about standard Java `Properties`, then keys must be present. Don't agree?

Comment: Yes. But I mean something like: `001 = Jhon 002 = Smith`. Just without `user#` prefix at the beginning of each line.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov nobody claims, that considered property file can't contain some additional information about each user.